# Python Convert Folder of .tsv files to separate folder of .csv files

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I'm trying to use python to convert a folder of .tsv files to a separate folder of .csv files. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

data = {}
for filename in glob.glob('C:/Users/user/Documents/Data/*.tsv'):
    tsv_file=filename
    csv_table=pd.read_table(tsv_file,sep='\t')
    csv_table.to_csv(filename,index=False)
```

Currently getting the error "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 32, saw 424" and I'm unsure on how to use pandas to save the converted csv files to a separate folder.

[Example TSV file converted to excel (there are 310 of these)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0lfD.png)

Comment: Can you print `filename` for us? I think you just got the directory name. Assuming files end in ".tsv", you'd need `'C;/Users/usr/Documents/Data/*.tsv'`. Then you need to change that file name to the output directory.

Comment: Did any of the files convert or did the error happen on the first file? For the file that had the problem would be helpful to know what's on line 1 and line 32.

Comment: Error happened on first file. The tsv files have 32 rows that contain info about the testing equipment (first column contains the name of the variable and 2nd column says the variable). After that the tsv files have a very large table that contains the results of the tests. I would like the whole file to be converted, but as long as the table starting on row 32 is converted its fine.

Comment: Looks like there are extra separators in line 32 of the tsv file, and hence while reading, it is getting more columns that expected in line 32. Can you paste a snapshot of how .tsv file looks.

Comment: Added an image of the tsv file to the original question.